# jQuery is it safe to iterate $.get()?

Tags: jquery, thread-safety

I'm having a problem binding dropdowns.  I think the problem is the callback in my `$.get()`.  Is it unsafe to perform gets in a loop?  E.G.

```
//on document ready
var stateOneOrTwo = "stateOne";
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
   if(i === 1)
       stateOneOrTwo = "stateTwo";

   $.get(url,{},function(data) {
    var dropdown = stateOneOrTwo;
    $(dropdown).append(/*options*/);
   , 'json')};
}
```

---

This does appear to be unsafe.  I threw DRY principles out the window.  When I copy paste the code and just change the variable names involved I do not have any issues.  I'll leave the question open for a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing stateOneOrTwo before the XHR comes back, so both callbacks will be running with `stateOneOrTwo` equal to `"stateTwo"`.  If you are just calling get twice, you don't really need a loop.

```
$.get(url,{},function(data) {
    var dropdown = "stateOne";
    $(dropdown).append(/*options*/);
}, 'json');

$.get(url,{},function(data) {
    var dropdown = "stateTwo";
    $(dropdown).append(/*options*/);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same problem?  If `stateOneOrTwo` changes for both get requests, why would `i` stay the same?

Comment: Yep, I realized that after submitting it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  As Rikudo pointed out, there is probably a better way to handle what it is I am doing.  But, for now this works.

Answer (score 1):

I am entirely not sure whether `$.get` will fail if you call a new one before it is finished, however, a more safe (and correct) approach would be to use recursive functions to make sure the request is complete before sending the next one.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'm not familiar with recursive functions.  I'll have to look into this as a refactor when I get the basic layout finished.  Though, I would rather create parallel requests for speed.